# Why does gRPC have twice the throughput of HTTP/2+protobuf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am doing benchmarks on different transfer protocols in java+spring-boot, and one thing that stands out is just how much higher throughput gRPC has compared to HTTP/2 with protobuf. The difference becomes even higher with concurrent calls. I'm wondering what is the 'secret sauce' that makes it faster.

JMH results:

```
protobufHttp2  thrpt   25  2196,489 ±  47,739  ops/s
grpc           thrpt   25  4650,875 ±  51,356  ops/s
```

HTTP/2 client setup

```
HttpAsyncClients.customHttp2()
                    .setDefaultConnectionConfig(ConnectionConfig.custom()
                            .setTimeToLive(TimeValue.ofMinutes(10))
                            .build())
                    .setTlsStrategy(ClientTlsStrategyBuilder.create()
                            .setSslContext(selfSignSSLContext)
                            .build())

                    .build();
```

Comment: gRPC uses [Netty](https://netty.io/) which is known for high performance, low latency and optimized memory usage. I am assuming `HttpAsyncClients` does not use that?